# Code within nUnit works fine but within Windows Service gets HTTP status 403: Forbidden when calling a remote Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, security, windows-services, windows-xp

**Context**
I'm working a c# module which is responsible to integrate our business with an external entity as part of our SOA system. The external entity provides web services. They're a throughly tested as it is a federal government product.
The module has been developed using test-driven approach, we use nUnit and everything was fine during test.

**Security**
Public certificates is basic requirement to connect to the web services. The following line is used: X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("Application.cer");

**Problem**
During test, the remote web service was succesfully connected and business rules were throughly tested. Requirements demanded that this module should be used as a windows service application. After deployment, the remote web service calls results in "HTTP status 403: Forbidden".
Seems that coding is not an issue as the same module works fine within nUnit environment and only doesn't work within Windows Service.

**Development Environment**
 - Windows XP 
 - Vistual Studio 2008 
 - Nunit
 - C#

**Already been tried**
 1. Running the Windows Service impersonated by a local administrator account. 
 2. Add the program to exception list on windows firewall.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should post the code that hosts your module in a Windows service.

Comment: @bernard It works when we're testing using nUnit application. But when it comes to windows service it raises a communication error. It doesn't seem to be the code. Perhaps the configuration settings or security.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the service from a different account which has administrative priveliges. It will give error if run under LocalSystem account.

Comment: Long ago. I don't know exactly how I solved this problem but your approach is correct too. Thanks!